# JS: convert a matrix of bytes into image

Tags: javascript, image, byte

I'm getting in JS code a 2D matrix of bytes (integer values between 0-255) from a camera and I want to display it in a `<canvas>` element. Is there a way to convert this matrix to an image?

I have tried to use `window.atob()` but it fails and stopped to execute the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You need to to something like this (example for a 120x120 image):

Html:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width=120 height=120></canvas>
```

JS:

```
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var imgData = ctx.createImageData(120, 120);
// Now you need to assign values to imgData array into groups of four (R-G-B-A)
let j = 0;
iterate your object {
    imgData.data[j] = R value;
    imgData.data[j + 1] = G value;
    imgData.data[j + 2] = B value;
    imgData.data[j + 3] = 255 (if greyscale);
    j += 4;
}
ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
```